# Python passing default value to combobox class : all instances show same value

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter

I am writing a program which analyses a CSV file containing my credit card monthly statement. I am trying to create a gui with tkinter in which I have a row of label headings followed by rows which consist of 3 more labels and then a combobox in the 4th column which has a number of categories. I have written a class which defines each row of the table. I want to pass a value to the instance of the class which specifies the initial value for the combobox. This is different for each instance or row. Or at least should be....

My problem is that in passing in different numbers for each row/instance I always get all rows having the value specified for the first created instance.
My classes are as follows:

```
class CatFormApp:

def __init__(self,parent):
    self.parent = parent        
    self.datelabel = Tkinter.Label(root, text='Date',font  ='Verdana 12 bold',borderwidth=5).grid(row=0,column=0)        
    self.transactionlabel = Tkinter.Label(root, text='Transactions',font  ='Verdana 12 bold',borderwidth=5).grid(row=0,column=1)
    self.paidoutlabel = Tkinter.Label(root, text='Paid Out',font  ='Verdana 12 bold',borderwidth=5).grid(row=0,column=2)
    self.catlabel = Tkinter.Label(root, text='Category',font  ='Verdana 12 bold',borderwidth=5).grid(row=0,column=3)        



class RowFormat:
    def __init__(self,parent,rownumbval,defaultval,dateval,transactionval,paidoutval,CatTupleVals,bkg):
        self.parent = parent
        self.datevallabel = Tkinter.Label(root, text=dateval, borderwidth=5).grid(row=rownumbval,column=0)
        self.transactionvallabel = Tkinter.Label(root, text=transactionval, borderwidth=5, background = bkg).grid(row=rownumbval,column=1)        
        self.paidoutvallabel = Tkinter.Label(root, text=paidoutval, borderwidth=5).grid(row=rownumbval,column=2)        
        self.combo(rownumbval,defaultval,CatTupleVals) 

    def combo(self,rownumb,default,CatTuple):
        self.box_value = '1'
        self.box = ttk.Combobox(self.parent,textvariable = self.box_value)
        self.box['values']=CatTuple
        self.box.current(default)
        self.box.grid(row=rownumb,column=3)
```

The relevant bit of my main code is:

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()


app = CatFormApp(root)
row = ['']*(len(CreditData['Transactions'])+1)
for r in range(1,len(CreditData['Transactions'])):
    if CreditData['Paid out'][r-1] != '':
        if noMatch[r-1] == True: 
            print 1
            row[r] = RowFormat(root,r,1,CreditData['Date'][r-1],CreditData['Transactions'][r-1],CreditData['Paid out'][r-1][1:],tuple(CatHeadings[:-1]),bkg = 'red')
        else:
            print 2
            row[r] = RowFormat(root,r,2,CreditData['Date'][r-1],CreditData['Transactions'][r-1],CreditData['Paid out'][r-1][1:],tuple(CatHeadings[:-1]),bkg = 'white smoke')

root.mainloop()
```

In the above example all comboboxes have the value associated with 1. Whereas I should get some with a 1 and some with a 2 depending on the if statement. I'm puzzled because I do something very similar for the other label values passed and these all come out differently as expected.

If someone could explain where I'm going wrong I'd be really grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
self.box_value = '1'
self.box = ttk.Combobox(...,textvariable = self.box_value)
```

The value for the `textvariable` attribute must be an instance of the tkinter class `StringVar` (or one of the other special tkinter variables).

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. What is the textvariable doing? I thought the value initially shown was being set by the self.box.current(value).

Comment: @MikeS: from the documentation: _"Specifies the name of a global variable whose value is linked to the widget value. Whenever the variable changes value the widget value is updated, and vice versa."_

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
self.box_value = Tkinter.StringVar()
self.box = ttk.Combobox(self.parent,textvariable = self.box_value)
```

To set values, use:

```
self.box['values'] = ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

To select the first item, use:

```
self.box.current(0)
```